# UIPickerViewDelegate method does not act while subclassing UIPickerView

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm trying to make a custom date picker. I've subclassed `UIPickerView` and made it `UIPickerViewDataSource` and `UIPickerViewDelegate` in both `init(coder:)` and `init(frame:)`:

```
class XKPickerView: UIPickerView, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.dataSource = self
    self.delegate = self
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    self.dataSource = self
    self.delegate = self
}

(...)
}
```

But the delegate function `pickerView(titleForRow:)` is not being called upon the view loads. I think, I'm missing something in `init()`, but what?

**Add**: I'm using storyboard to construct views.

**Add 2**: pickerView code has much dummies yet, but even simple `return "abc"` in general does not act, because the function itself is not being called (double checked with print() and debugger).

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, 
                forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    switch component {
    case 0: // day label
        return String(row + 1)
    case 1: // month label (localized)
        return "0"
    case 2: // century label
        return "0"
    case 3: // year of the century label
        return String(row + 1)
    case 4: // era label (localized)
        return "0"
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure you set number of rows? Cause if it's zero that method won't get called.

Comment: Yes I did, and the count is different, because I want picker to be like 21 | February | 16 | 35 | BC. Each section has different amount of ?s, for example the least representing era has two.

Comment: Show your `pickerView(titleForRow:)` code? or at least the definition?

Comment: @DonMag added to the question

Comment: @A.I.A. I was wondering if you had a typo... for example, if you had `titleFrRow` (missing an 'o'), you'd get no error or warning, it just wouldn't get called. But --- it looks correct. Are any other Delegate funcs being called?

Comment: @DonMag, nope. Just tested it with simple `func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat { return 30 } ` and debugger, because have not implemented any other delegate functions before.

Comment: Is the delegate function inside the subclassed UIPickerView class?

Comment: @muazhud, yes it is. I'm going to implement another delegate protocol for real delegation. This is used just to tune UIPickerView to make it a date picker

Comment: You need specify the `titleForRow` inside the subclass but not at the storyboard.

Comment: @muazhud I did it already

Comment: I've done a custom date picker, but I had better luck using an embedded controller (acting as the datasource/delegate) which I then storyboarded, rather than going the subclass route.

Comment: Did you try to create it programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what's going on with your attempt, but I just did this and it's working without issue...

```
class MyPickerView: UIPickerView, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.dataSource = self
        self.delegate = self
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        self.dataSource = self
        self.delegate = self
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return "Row \(row)"
    }

}
```

That's the entire class.

Comment: I've copied and pasted your answer, it also did not work but gave me a solution, what is wrong! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for answers! I was missing, that I've added a `pickerView.delegate = self` in ViewDidLoad() of a corresponding view controller. What a disgrace :)